# UEFI: getting rEFInd to parse it's configuration file

Tags: boot, uefi, efi, refind

I installed refind as my UEFI boot manager. The automatic install script did nothing, so I added a boot entry manually, but now i cannot get it to read the options on refind.conf. I am not sure when that file is ever used by refind.

my sytem is set up as:

```
   /dev/sda1, fat, mounted as /boot (contains /boot/EFI)
   /dev/sda3, ext4, mounted as /
```

I've edited `/boot/EFI/refind/refind.conf` to add my kernel options. Which are just `root=/dev/sda3 video=1024x768`

If I run the refind install script, it will say it found the file, and leave a another file with the defaults next to the file i've edited.

When i boot, i get no kernel options. I have to press F2 and type it everytime.

How can i get refind to use that conf file, or how i can simpy save my kernel parameters?

I am using archlinux if that matters.

Comment: Unless you're setting up manual boot stanzas, kernel options do *not* go in `refind.conf`; they go in `refind_linux.conf`, which lives in the same directory as the Linux kernel (normally `/boot`). You can build this file automatically by running the `mkrlconf` script from your system that's booted in whatever way you can get to work. Manual boot stanzas are much harder to set up than kernel auto-detection, so I recommend relying on the latter in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

@Rodsmith comment is very relevant. Always try to use the automatic detection. And i didn't know about mkrlconf, though i didn't need it to solve for my case.

In my case, the autoscript would just detect the boot partition and its kernel. No kernel options at all! Even when i had just booted manually entering those options, the autoscript would ignore them.

I had to simply create the /boot/refind_linux.conf file and it worked fine. It was a little confusing what to set as the boot id to match the kernel it found. Actually, very confusing and I am still not sure i understand the string matching logic. But that file is read at runtime. So no need to run anything, that is the answer to this i think. Just edit the file and reboot to try it out.